# Detect if a number is between 2 others?

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to detect if a number, is between two other numbers? Is there already a function to do this in the Math object?

Comment: Excuse me, but this is not math :)

Answer (score 9):

There is no specific function, but you can do it like this:

```
lowNumber < yourNumber && yourNumber < highNumber
```

Comment: I prefer to use `min < n && n < max` because then it looks sort of like `min < n < max`.

Comment: ^^ Certainly nothing wrong with that. It does have a nice flow to it.

Answer (score 3):

Though the code solution is fairly obvious, if you're going to use it a lot, you may want to implement it on `Number.prototype` for convenience:

```
Number.prototype.inRange = function( a,b ) {
    var n = +this;
    return ( n > a && n < b );
};
```

So you'd use it like this:

```
(5).inRange( 3, 7 ); // true
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dTHQ3/

Answer (score 2):

Um if it is greater than one and less than the other.

```
var num1 = 3;
var num2 = 5;
var x = 4;
var isBetween = (num1 < x && num2 > x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( yournumber < highNumber && yournumber > lowNumber ){    
  // do something    
} else {    
  // do something else    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only optimized way to do this is to guess which is more likely: Is the number your checking more likely to be lower than the lower bound, or is it more likely to be higher than the upper bound?

With this in mind, you can take advantage of [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) by placing the more likely failure check first (if it fails that, it won't test the less likely criteria). This is the only way to optimize it.

Even this will save you the smallest amount of time that is most likely not going to be noticed. Perhaps if you were making this check millions of times, you might save a fraction of a second over the alternative.